# Get order data in different language?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, i18n

I'm trying to fetch the order and/or the product data, but translated to a specific language/store view from an observer. This will send out an internal email so the order will be handled. Im calling the order data like this:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    // Stuff
}
```

And product Data

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        $itemData = $item->getData();
        // Stuff
}
```

I've tried adding `->setStoreId(X)` to the above but that didn't help.

Can it be done on the complete order object? Can it be done on the product level, including attributes? Or is this a case of fetching it one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Use the object managers with product id for the product data.

```
$product_id      = 1; // for example

$objectManager   = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productData     = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

$productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($product_id);
```

`Show all product data as well as arrays, variables and values:`

```
foreach($productData->getProductOptionsCollection() as $o){
    foreach($o->getValues() as $ov){
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($ov->getData()); echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

`Show Stock Data:`

```
$productStockObj->getData());
```

`Get Current Store Id:`

```
$storeManager  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

echo $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to dive into your answer sooner. While I appreciate your effort, please tell me where do you actually change the storeview/language? Let's say my main view is DE, the order is coming in FR and I want to get all the information in EN

Comment: Do you also want to retrieve the product data or do you only mean order data per Store Id.

Comment: I want to retrieve all the data of the order passed by the observer, but translated to a different language/storeview. So product(name), its custom options (labels) but preferably also things like shipping/payment options